# Is it required to commit .ballerina to version control

Tags: version-control, project, ballerina

With `ballerina init` a `.ballerina` directory is being created at the working directory.

Is it required to commit the content inside the directory in order to share the project in a version control environment like git?

Inside `.ballerina` it contains a `repo` directory and a `.gitignore` file which seems important to the application. Since `ballerina` is a new language I'm not aware of best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Committing `.ballerina` directory and `Ballerina.toml` file allows the second person who checkout your repo to use that code as a ballerina project without doing ballerina init them self. So I guess it's better to commit those, but I don't think you need to commit the content of `.ballerina` directory if there's any.